# Multilevel Inheritance Error "cout does not name a type"

Tags: c++, inheritance

> Cout Does not Name a Type

Folks, why I am getting this error even I am using "iostream and using namespace std"

Here is My Code

```
   class DateType: public PatientType{

    cout<<"\nEnter Patient ID\n";
    cin>>Patient_ID;
    cout<<"\nEnter  Patient's Age\n";
    cin>>Age;
    cout<<"\nEnter Patient's Date of Birth";
    cin>>DOB;
};
```

Class DateType is Derived from class PatientType and class PatientType is Dervied from Class PersonType.

cout is working everywhere but in class DateType.

Comment: You might want to get [a good book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/253056).

Comment: What are you trying to do? When do you want those lines of code to be run? You will get the same error even without using inheritnce.

Comment: My bad, I was assuming that I am writing code in a function but that was in class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cout<<"\nEnter Patient ID\n";` is a *statement* that needs to be inside a *function*.

This, and your other statements, are floating somewhere in the class definition. This is not syntactically valid.

This is confusing the compiler and is issuing a somewhat cryptic error.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is outside any function, and this is incorrect.